# Getting the whole object from an option with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angularJs html:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedObj"
                        ng-options="x.Id as x.Title for x in myData">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                </select>
```

Using this html, the ng-model="SelectedObj" will receive the Id property from myData in the currently selected option. Is there a simple way with angularjs to keep the display settings for the option value, but return the entire object to the ng-Model instead of just the Id property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="SelectedObj"
                    ng-options="x as x.Title for x in myData">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
```